# Getting mp3 data from google app engine's blobstore via ajax

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery

I'm trying to store audio files in google app engine's blobstore and play them in a browser. The problem I'm running into is that the data I'm getting in the browser is the actual mp3 data. I was expecting to get a url to play the mp3 in the blobstore. So, my question is, what do I need to change to get a url to play the blob instead of the audio data?

Here is my server side handler.

```
class ServeBlobHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
def get(self):

    user = users.get_current_user()
    query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM AudioData Where userId = :1", user.user_id())

    results = query.fetch(limit=300)
    for dStoreEntry in results:

        entityBlobInfo = dStoreEntry.audioBlob

    self.send_blob(entityBlobInfo)
```

This is the client side.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/serve_blob/audio/',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'text',
    success : function(data) {
        alert('GET, audio data : \n '+ data );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL of the page that you're currently fetching the data from *is* the URL of the MP3. You'll need to use a web-based player of some sort to play it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If I'm fetching the data from the blobstore, there is no url to a page, right? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Justin You need to write a handler to serve up the blob - which you've already done. Enter the URL for that handler, and you get the blob back.

Comment: Yeah, it's up to you to decide what the url is going to be. We use a url like /media/serve/<blobkey> so it can be cached by google's front end edge caching.

Comment: That's great, thanks! Rick, that sounds like a good structure but, how do you get the blobkey on the client side before you put in the request to the server? Also, the audio only plays for about two seconds. Is there something I need to do to make sure the all the data is passed to the client?

Answer (score 0):

What `Content-type` header does your browser get for mp3 request? I'm guessing it's `application/octet-stream`

See what Blobstore docs say about upload:

```
If you don't specify a content type, the Blobstore will try to infer it from the 
file extension. If no content type can be determined, the newly created blob is 
assigned content type application/octet-stream
```

Go to GAE admin pages and check Blob Viewer to see under what content type was assigned to your mp3 files.

Comment: The content-type is set to "audio/mp3". The file name also ends in a .mp3 so the blobstore should know what type of data is there.

Comment: I tested Chrome and Firefox and they natively play mp3 files if content type is set to `audio/mpeg`. See: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3

Comment: Also, I've searched around and could not find URLs that serve `audio/mp3`. Maybe you should set your content type to `audio/mpeg` to make it play natively in browsers.

Comment: I changed the "audio/mp3" to to "audio/mpeg". I get the same result of passing all the audio data to the request. I get what your saying now of the browser natively knowing how to play mp3 files. Based on this I think I need to change my question to how to I get the url from the handler not the audio data.

Answer (score 0):

Get JPlayer - http://www.jplayer.org/

And then your example should work fine. We use it with appengine blobstore in java and it's great. The url from the blobstore will work in jplayer.

You can also set cache headers on your blob urls if you rewrite them to remove any query parameters and save yourself the costs of serving each stream.

Comment: I don't have the url at this point, just the mp3 file data. What I want to know is how to get a url. Any help on that would be great!

Comment: eh, see my comment above justin.. it's up to you to make a url to get the blob from. Put the blobkey in the url /media/serve/<key> and then read it from there.